# QML: Current Index / Item is changin if swipeview is populated using a loader or repater inside a asyncronous parent Loader

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

Dynamic loading data into a QML SwipeView loaded asyncronous is autmomatically increment the current index.

```
Loader{
    asynchronous: true
    anchors.fill: parent
    sourceComponent:  ColumnLayout{
        //Any content here that can take some time to load
        TabBar{
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Repeater{
                model: swRepeater.model
                delegate: TabButton{
                    text: "Tab button "+index
                }
            }
        }

        SwipeView{
            //                    anchors.fill: parent
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            currentIndex: 0
            Repeater{
                id: swRepeater
                model: 5
                delegate: Item{
                    Label{
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: qsTr("Test "+index)
                    }
                }
            }
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                console.debug("Index was modified to ",currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the loading data the current item and index will be 4, and not 0 as explected.

Also is displayed the last item from stack.

The same behavior can be se on the TabBar item so the problem looks to came from ListView or Container.

Any suggestion on this behavior?

Comment: How about adding `Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = 0` to your `SwipeView` ?

Comment: @StephenQuan No, is not working.
The main reason is that the bug is keeping the currentIndex 0. Only the items ar "scrolled" to the last inserted item.
As a workaround can be (considering SwipeView has and id "swipeView")
swipeView.contentItem is a ListView so will need to scroll it back to 0,0 or to Beginning which is not the best thing to do.

`swipeView.contentItem.positionViewAtBeginning()`